# Trying to call two extensions of UIView on the same UIView element

Tags: ios, swift

I have made a custom class of `UIView` that draws a card with some information on it, and I am trying to round the corners of the card and add a shadow to it.  I have written functions that do both of those things as extensions of `UIView`, but when I make the two function calls, it only applies the function that was called last.

```
class InfoCard: UIView {

@IBOutlet var CardView: UIView!        

private func commonInit() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("InfoCard", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(CardView)

        CardView.roundCorners(cornerRadius: 15.0)
        CardView.dropShadow()            

    }

}

extension UIView {
    func roundCorners(cornerRadius: Double) {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(cornerRadius)
        self.clipsToBounds = true
      }
    }

extension UIView {

    func dropShadow(scale: Bool = true) {        
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        layer.shadowRadius = 5

        layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds).cgPath
        layer.shouldRasterize = true
        self.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have two separate extensions, the first is for corner radius, and the second for the drop shadow.  Again, these both function as they should, but when I call the both of them in `commonInit()`, only the last one called is applied (in this case, the drop shadow is the one applied).  How can I get both styles to be applied?

Comment: Change the CardView background color and check it is applying the cornerRadius or not ?

Comment: @vivekDas I have checked both functions independently and I have seen that they both do function as needed

Comment: Odd. Maybe this is a stupid question, but can I assume you've *combined* this code into one call and tested *both* sequences and found the same issue?

Comment: @dfd I've tried that also, but it only applies the shadow in that case (I don't know why it would not apply the rounded corners though)

Comment: One more question? Your question - the part about calling the last function only working - suggest that had you combined *and* reversed the sequence, the rounded corners would be the only thing applied?

Comment: where is `commonInit` called?  is `CardView` already in your `InfoCard` xib file (since I see you marked it as an `@IBOutlet`)?  If so, why are you adding it as a subview to `InfoCard`?  Also, variables really need to start with lower case letters (e.g. `infoCard` and `cardView`).

Comment: @dfd exactly.  When I combine the functions, instead of it going by the order it is called in `commonInit()`, it goes by the order the styles are defined in the extension itself

Comment: @MichaelDautermann my `InfoCard` xib file is the child to the `InfoCard` swift file in which the `commonInit` is called

Comment: Your issue is someplace else. I took the two extensions you posted, and created a simple project that (1) creates a UIView with an orange background color, added it to the view hierarchy *after* calling your extension function in `viewDidLoad`. It works perfectly. As suggested in another comment I'd look into how you are initializing things. EDIT: I also did everything in code. No nib files.

Comment: @dfd oh man, this got a bit more frustrating.  Thanks for taking the time to try it out though!